# How to spawn a Flask App PER user in gunicorn

Tags: api, flask, gunicorn, wsgi

I have a flask app that saves some data based on user input. However, I want that data to be  personalized for each user. I tried running the app with gunicorn with 2 threads and 1 worker, as well as 1 thread and 2 workers. In both cases, whenever I open two tabs on my browser and interact with my frontend (served with nginx), the change is reflected on both tabs. I want the change to be specific to whoever made the change.

One way I've thought of solving this problem was saving the data in my flask app as a dictionary, where the keys are user session ids or something to identify the user, and the values, the data specific for that user. However, I want to know if gunicorn has some config options to spawn a single app PER USER (not request). Does gunicorn have such capabilities?

Thanks!

Comment: Gunicorn workers are not meant for this purpose.  Typically you would implement a login system with a `User` table in the database, then save your 'input' in a separate table with a foreign key column to the `User` table, allowing each user to see only their own inputed data.  Gunicorn workers should just handle the request and let the app's code do the user filtering logic, based on the provided session/cookie.  Having gunicorn spawn a worker per user would also lead to scaling issues.  Without seeing code samples of what you're trying to achieve it's difficult to help further.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for.